# A position that claims meanings can't be abstract (but abstract objects still might exist)?

Tags: semantics, meaning, platonism, abstract

Is my titular question trivial, vacuous, encompasses every philosopher ever, none ever, or only encompasses a non-empty subset? I think there are different positions on it.

If meanings aren't abstract, it doesn't mean denying abstract objects exist, it just means the relationship/correspondence between meaning and them is more pragmatic than someone like Frege or most platonists of mathematics would have it, I think.

Is there such an established position in philosophy and where can I find it? Do proponents all fall into one camp, like pragmatism, detractors in another (what)? Or have I made a category error such as of course meanings aren't abstract? What can be said? Thanks

I know of Jody Azzouni, who is a nominalist but thinks standard mathematical sentences are still true in the original form. I think he looks to our uses in language to derive truth from what I can tell. I guess this would be different in that it would leave open abstract objects still existing.

Comment: Technically, this would be the position of most nominalists. Why settle themselves with making arguments for non-existence of X when it is easier to argue that it is redundant? But, off the philosophical record, they are often upfront, Azzouni especially, that abstract objects are an irrelevant metaphysical extravagance that we can darn well do without. It is similar to atheism/agnosticism, Laplace's "I did not need that hypothesis" or abstract objects as Epicurus's do-nothing "gods". Reminiscent of the [motte-and-bailey tactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motte-and-bailey_fallacy).

Comment: @Conifold Don't know if it was on purpose but you sound exactly like Azzouni here , "can darn well do without", hah. I can see why a practiced writer and poet like he is confident enough to go the extra step in his nominalism by having such attention to how language is used broadly. It elevates how "powerful" humans are, rather than makes their reasoning shakier without abstracta. Interesting stuff, never would have known these are still nominalists. Thanks